# How to detect if user in on the last page in Django REST (pagination)?

Tags: python, django, pagination, django-rest-framework

Suppose I have a view:

```
class FooPagination(PageNumberPagination):
    page_size = 10

class FooView(ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = FooSerializer
    pagination_class = FooPagination
    def get_queryset(self):
        if self.paginator.?
            # do something special
```

How to detect if user is on the last page in Django REST (pagination)?

**Update** If I try to:

```
print(self.paginator.get_next_link())
```

I get:

```
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value: 'FooPagination' object has no attribute 'page'
Exception Location: C:\Users\Daniel\venvs\brook\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\pagination.py in get_next_link, line 297
```

I guess what I am trying is not possible this way as the paginator does not know if it is on the last page until the query set is specified.  Kind of chicken and egg situation.

Comment: Try using has_next() which will tell you that a paginator has next page available or not

Comment: self.paginator.has_next() gives Exception Type: AttributeError, Exception Value: 'FooPagination' object has no attribute 'has_next'.

Comment: Follow this link http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/pagination/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For **self.paginator.get_next_link()** to work, you have to use  **self.paginate_queryset(self.queryset)**. And usually, this is used inside view methods such as list() instead of get_queryset()(Both works anyway!).

Then, use

```
 if not self.paginator.get_next_link():
     #  You're in last page
     #  your code goes here
```